# how to login php login joomla 2.5 with another server

Tags: encryption, joomla2.5

I tried building an offline php application integrated with online website joomla 2.5.

Now I need help how I can login with user password (as the user registered in online website) in the offline application.

Here, I try get a password from database:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', '/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

JFactory::getApplication('site')->initialise();

$userid = '1043';
$user = JFactory::getUser($userid);

$joomla_name = $user->name;
$joomla_email = $user->email;
$joomla_password = $user->password;
$joomla_username = $user->username;

echo $joomla_name."</br>";
echo $joomla_email."</br>";
echo $joomla_password."</br>";
echo $joomla_username."</br>";

?>
```

result is : name, email, password,username

```
Rohmad Arifin
arifin_rohmad@yahoo.com
$P$DofxvVE7B682K.8tyUdp5FJ41DhTvG.
arifin
```

I need get decrypt password for authentication login.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this is:

If joomla did their login right, it's close to impossible. The point of encrypting (or in this case probably hashing with a salt) is that the password is not restorable from the outside. The goal here is preventing identity theft.

You should instead use a custom code for your offline application. Alternatively you could take the already hashed / encrypted password as cleartext authenticator. And just do what joomla did to the password before checking it in your offline application.